# Hive describe partitions to show partition url

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, hive

I know that there is

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED table_name;
```

that shows you the table format. 
Is there a way to get a more information about partitions apart from

```
SHOW PARTITIONS table_name;
```

I saw that Hive language manual has this

```
DESCRIBE [EXTENDED|FORMATTED] [db_name.]table_name PARTITION partition_spec
```

I would like to view all the partitions along with the url in hdfs or s3 where the data is stored.

Answer (score 16):

To show partitions:

`show partitions table_name`

To show where a partition is physically stored:

`describe formatted dbname.tablename partition (name=value)`

I don't know of a built-in way to create an output that is (partition, path) but you can build it using these two commands and some grep/awk or whatever.

Comment: If the table has 2 or more partitions?

Comment: Yes, if the table has more partitions, you use show partitions table_name. Then you have to describe each of the partitions if you want more information.

Answer (score 3):

```
analyze table TABLENAME partition(the_partition) compute statistics nopass;
```

The above code gives you more info about the partitions (number of files, number of rows, total size), but doesn't give you exact location.

If you want exact location, you may want to create an external table.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to describe the partition and get the partition URL's

1. Using DESCRIBE FORMATTED

   DESCRIBE FORMATTED zipcodes PARTITION(state='PR');
2. Using SHOW TABLE EXTENDED

   SHOW TABLE EXTENDED LIKE zipcodes PARTITION(state='PR');
3. Running HDFS command. Use this if you know all partitions are stored at the same location.

   hdfs dfs -ls /<table_name>
4. If you just wanted to know the existing partitions on the table

   SHOW PARTITIONS <table_name>

You can find more details with output at [Hive Show all Table Partitions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hive/hive-show-all-table-partitions/)