# Should 'show table extended' list the files under partitions?

Tags: hive, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

I have separated files by year for an external table. I added partitions for each year. I ran the show table extended command and it shows:

```
partitioned:true
partitionColumns:struct partition_columns { i32 year}
totalNumberFiles:0
totalFileSize:0
```

Should it list the files in each partition's location?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myTable(
    somefield STRING,
    somefield2 STRING,
    GMTDateTime TIMESTAMP
    )

PARTITIONED BY (year INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://{hdinsight instance}@{storage name}.blob.core.windows.net/data00/';

alter table myTable add partition ( year = 2015 ) location '{hdinsight instance}@{storage name}.blob.core.windows.net/data2015/' ;
alter table myTable add partition ( year = 2014 ) location '{hdinsight instance}@{storage name}.blob.core.windows.net/data2014/' ;
```

Comment: refer the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056402/hive-describe-partitions-to-show-partition-url

Comment: when I run

analyze table TABLENAME partition(the_partition) compute statistics nopass;

I get:

FAILED: ParseException line 1:55 extraneous input 'nopass' expecting EOF near ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry .. 
we can see individual partition location with the help of below command..
DESCRIBE [EXTENDED|FORMATTED] [db_name.]table_name PARTITION partition_spec...

But there is no such command to know all the partitions with urls.. we've to find it out by individual partition.

Comment: Being new to hive and hdfs, it just surprised me that when you define a table and add partitions to different locations, that show table extended does not list all the files in all the partitions.